# Why are these 2 elements NOT on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap to put 2 elements on the same row. However, I am having difficulties getting it to work.  Here is what I am inputting:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div>$</div>
            <div class="refundNumber">12345</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it outputs:

> $
>   12345

I want it to be:

> $12345

I cant simply put the "$" with the numbers because I will be using JS to count up the numbers from zero on a specific event. It doesn't work with the "$" present.

Thank you in advance for helping a beginner!

Comment: replace `div` with `span` for the $ and the amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>`s are block-level elements that start on new lines. If you want them to be on the same line, you have to make them inline-block or inline elements.

**Edit:** Using `<span>` would be the appropriate solution in your case:

Change:

```
<div>$</div>
<div class="refundNumber">12345</div>
```

To:

```
<span>$</span>
<span class="refundNumber">12345</span>
```

Comment: Or simply use <span>'s, which are inline elements and better suited for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Right, span would be semantically appropriate. @AndrewLittle would need to make both the $ `<div>` and the `.refundNumber` into spans for them to be on the same line.

Comment: Thank you all! Both options were successful! I will use <span>.

Comment: @timolawl it looks like you mistakingly closed the `span` tag with a `div`

Answer (score 0):

Like "Dov Benyomin" answered, except apply ascii character to ensure compatibility.

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
     <span>&#36;</span>
     <span class="refundNumber">12345</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this :

```css
.text{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--Use span tags -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span>&#36;</span>
    <span class="refundNumber text">12345</span>
  </div>
</div>

<span>OR</span>
<!--Best method use display:inline -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text">&#36;</div>
    <div class="refundNumber text">12345</div>
  </div>
</div>

<span>OR</span>
<!-- Using col classes of bootstrap -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-1">&#36;</div>
    <div class="refundNumber">12345</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Like Micheal pointed out, use ASCII codes. ("& #36;" for "$")